# How to find a specific substring in a specific range in Python

Tags: python, string

I have a file that contains a String and i want to search for a substring in a specific range, This is my string:

```
newick;
((raccoon,bear),((sea_lion, seal),((monkey,cat), weasel)),dog);
```

And this is my code for it:

```
def removeNewick(tree):
    for x in tree:
        new_set = x.replace('newick;', '')
    print(new_set)


filepath = "C:\\Users\\msi gaming\\Desktop\\small_tree.tre"
tree = open(filepath)
removeNewick(tree)
```

But i know for sure that if this string 'newick' is going to appear, then it would be in the first 10 characters of the string so how do i edit my for loop only to loop over the first ten characters?

Comment: you could test if you find the pattern in the sliced string, but I think it would take more time to slice the string than to perform the replace on the whole string. Are you looking for performance?

Comment: BTW how was this tree file generated, why do you have to parse it now to remove the newick word? This seems odd. (For those who don't know newick is a file format for storing trees https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newick_format)

Comment: It's a small dataset and i usually use the ETE3 library to read it but that fails when the word Newick is at the beginning.

Comment: what tool *generates* the tree with the word `newick;`?

Comment: "it would be in the first 10 characters of the string" do you mean "of the file" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so, tree is a file

```
def remove_newick(tree):
    for x in tree:
        if x.startswith('newick;'):
            print('')
        else:
            print(x)
```

[`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) is a string method that only checks as many characters as needed, and is the most efficient way to check if a string starts with a certain substring.

---

For the record, don't do

```
tree = open(filepath)
remove_newick(tree)
```

It's dangerous to not close files. Instead do

```
with open(filepath) as tree:
    remove_newick(tree)
```

Comment: but OP stated that "f this string 'newick' is going to appear, then it would be in the first 10 characters of the string", not necessarily at the start...

Comment: glad it worked. make sure to mark this as correct so we don't get answer spam and such

Comment: This is incorrect. This removes "newick" from the start of *any* line in the file, not just from the first 10 characters in the file.

Comment: @Aran-Fey what? "But i know for sure that if this string 'newick' is going to appear, then it would be in the first 10 characters of the string". he means each line string.

Comment: There are optional parameters which give indexes for the start and end of the search anyway. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_startswith.htm "str" "beg" "end"

Comment: even so, it is not correct: your code checks the start of each line.

Comment: Even if the OP *did* mean that, your code doesn't do that. It removes the text from the start of the line, not from the first 10 characters in the line.

Comment: Based on their actual application (feeding the tree to ETE3) I'm pretty sure removing all examples of `'newick;'` *is* the appropriate behaviour, the tool only needs the actual tree data contained within the paranetheses

Comment: @Chris_Rands Pretty much my interpretation. OP wants to skip lines which start with `"newick;"`. End of story.

Comment: ok, then it's a duplicate: "how to remove a starting pattern in each line of a file". This question sucks (and the answer doesn't bring anything new)

Comment: god jean that's so mean imma have to write a blog post about your behaviour of telling us a question sucked. <3

Comment: the _question_ sucks. Not targetting any user. I'll read your blog post.

Comment: whoosh...? i can't tell! :c